Placeholders for functions (like placeholders for vars in Strings)
I am new in flutter and programming, so don't e too harsh please. My problem is following:
I want to create a custom button for my menu entries and instead of classical text parameter, I want to parse an arb-key (or rather getter), so the AppLocalizations looks up for the key and returns corresponding getter in correct language.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';



class ExtendableMenuNavigationEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function() callback;
  final Function() arbGetter;

  const ExtendableMenuNavigationEntry({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.callback,
    required this.arbKey,
  });

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GFButton(
      onPressed: () => callback,
      text:  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.arbGetter,
      shape: GFButtonShape.pills,
      fullWidthButton: true,
    );
  }
}

However, I receive an error:
The getter 'arbGetter' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.
Try importing the library that defines 'arbGetter', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'arbKey'

AppLocalisation is autogenerated, I followed this guide: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization
Because of my inexperience, I am not even sure how I should call my problem. I know you can use placeholders for vars in Strings, but I have no idea how to do it for Functions...

The short answer is Dart simply doesn’t support this - it’s why you see so many packages with generators (like l10n itself)

@Clive aren't there any equivalent method as Class.getMethod in Java?

Not as of v3 of the language, no
